# Spring LDAP authentication NO_OBJECT

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect a Spring application to an AD-LDAP server. If I type the correct user/pass-data I get `NO_OBJECT`-error in the log:

```
DEBUG o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch - Searching for user 'THEUSER', with user search [ searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={0})', searchBase: 'DC=dev,DC=company,DC=local', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=entwicklung,dc=Lemken,dc=local', filter = '(sAMAccountName={0})'
DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Found DN: CN=THEUSER\, FirstName,OU=users,DC=dev,DC=company,DC=local
DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - Attempting to bind as cn=THEUSER\, FirstName,ou=users,dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local
DEBUG o.s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource - Removing pooling flag for user cn=THEUSER\, FirstName,ou=users,dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local
DEBUG o.s.s.l.u.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator - Getting authorities for user cn=THEUSER\, FirstName,ou=users,dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local
DEBUG o.s.s.l.u.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator - Searching for roles for user 'THEUSER', DN = 'cn=THEUSER\, FirstName,ou=users,dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local', with filter (uniqueMember={0}) in search base ''
DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Using filter: (uniqueMember=cn=THEUSER\5c, FirstName,ou=users,dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local)
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    ''
```

This is my configuration:

```
ContextSourceBuilder context = auth.ldapAuthentication()
  .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
  .userSearchBase("dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local")
  .contextSource();

context.port(389);
context
  .root("dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local")
  .url("ldap://example.com")
  .managerDn("cn=manager,ou=users,dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local")
  .managerPassword("thepassword");
```

If i type a wrong password I get "Bad password", so this part works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The key parts are:

```
Searching for roles
...
Using filter: (uniqueMember=
```

It is trying to find the user's roles - in AD those are the groups that the user is a member of. But it's doing that by searching groups that have the `uniqueMember` attribute set to the user. That attribute doesn't exist in AD. That is the default attribute name it uses since that's what's used in OpenLDAP.

You will need to use [`groupSearchFilter()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.html#groupSearchFilter-java.lang.String-) to change the attribute it looks at to find groups. AD uses the `member` attribute.

```java
ContextSourceBuilder context = auth.ldapAuthentication()
  .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
  .userSearchBase("dc=dev,dc=company,dc=local")
  .groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
  .contextSource();
```